# forEach not running inside lambda function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a Node.js AWS Lamba function which does a DB call then takes and splits the results of the DB call into different SQS messages. Currently it seems like that is broken as the Lambda is skipping over everything and when I add await (as seen below) it tells me I can't use await for the sendMessage portion.

```
module.exports.companyID = async (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    if (inter_conn == null) {
        inter_conn = await mongoose.createConnection(incident_Mongo_URI, {
            bufferCommands: false, // Disable mongoose buffering
            bufferMaxEntries: 0, // and MongoDB driver buffering
            useNewUrlParser: true // Required or it gives me an error
        });
    }

    const I = inter_conn.model('Incident');
    await I.find().distinct('companyID').exec(function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error(`Inter Cleanup: Find: Error message: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        logger.info(results)
        results.forEach(companyID => {
            let params = {
                MessageBody: companyID,
                QueueUrl: process.env.incidentsQueue,
                DelaySeconds: 0
            };

            let sendMessage = sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();

            await sendMessage.then((data) => {
                logger.info(data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                logger.error(err)
            })
        }); 
    })

    let output = {
        status: 'Done'
    }
    callback(null, output);
};
```

Error message as seen from Lambda console

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
    "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
  ]
}
```

I've tested the base code of this without the lambda related stuff and the async/await in a JS file ran as a script and it worked fine.

I know the issue lies in converting this to a lambda and has to do with Lambda's being async/await.

How can I make it so my Lambda does the DB call and runs the forEach putting each item in the results array into a SQS message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to `await` inside of your `forEach`, which is not `async`. Don't, however, think you can just make that an `async` function too.

The best solution to this is to stop using the `.forEach` and use the more modern `for/of`. Your for loop would look something like this:

```
        for (let companyID of results) {
            let params = {
                MessageBody: companyID,
                QueueUrl: process.env.incidentsQueue,
                DelaySeconds: 0
            };

            try {
                const data = await sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();

                logger.info(data)
            }
            catch (err) {
                logger.error(err);
            }
        }
```

**NOTE**, I've also changed the call the `sendMessage` to use a proper await.

Comment: Thank you that worked! So to understand a bit more, why is forEach not good to use with Lambda/in general? Also in the try catch, is it needed to use the `.promise()` still if I am not actually using `data` as a promise in my code?

Comment: the `.forEach` function doesn't work with async, so it won't work if you ned to `await` anything (not just in Lambda). For Lambdas you need to either use `async` or use callbacks. [See the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) on how that works. As for the `.promise()` you need that to use the `await`, which you need if you are in an `async` function.

Comment: Thank you makes much more sense now :)